# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.LauncherProtocol$Message

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, ubuntu-12.04

I at the time of running spark job in my project:

```
public static List<String> getAllSavedModelFoldersJob(String saveModelsFolderFilePath) {
    JavaSparkContext ctx = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        ctx = new JavaSparkContext(
              new SparkConf().setAppName("Save Models into File").setMaster("local"));
        list = getAllSavedModelFolders(ctx, saveModelsFolderFilePath).collect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return list;
    } finally { // ctx.stop(); } return list; }
    }
```

But getting below error,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.LauncherProtocol$Message
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend.(LocalBackend.scala:107)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2603)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:522)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
>       at com.nuevora.core.spark.SaveModelsJob.getAllSavedModelFoldersJob(SaveModelsJob.java:257)
>       at com.nuevora.controllers.FormsValidatorServlet.service(FormsValidatorServlet.java:546)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am using `spark` version is `spark-1.6`,`hadoop2.6` and `java1.8`.

Comment: Hi jodi,You have any idea please tell me

Comment: Can we see your build definition? Also what [tag:ubuntu-12.04] has to do with the question?